# show blank data when we fetch huge amount of data from database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch all the data from database but there show blank page because there is huge amount of data i.e 1000000 rows in the database table.
I was used simple sql query to fetch data i.e

```
  select * from 'table_name';
```

It works for little amount of data such as 1000 rows in the table but when data should be huge or large such as 100000+ there display blank page.

So please help me to solve out this problem
I would be thankful if anyone can give the good answer.

Comment: Please tell us more details: what are you going to do? Printing them in HTML format? Or your intention is something else?

Comment: What are your server capacity? Might be sql server gone away when you do such huge request.

Comment: you shouldn't render 100000 rows to the dom anyways. you should try and implement an infinite scroll that uses a page and offset for a limit in your query

Comment: You could use `LIMIT 0,1000` or `LIMIT 1000,2000` and so on.

Comment: I just want to fetch whole data from database table and display it as table form.

Comment: Why an user interface should present 100k records to a user?

Comment: This page will take a long time to load and render. Not very useful!

Comment: I have a huge amount of data which need to display in the table form

Comment: Do you want to display it as a html table? or anything like simply retrieving in mysql/ sql workbench?

Comment: for html tables, use limit with pagination!

Comment: simple retrieving form mysql and display it in html table

Answer (score 0):

If your are in production server the blank page can be an error in your php script. I bet to memory error

First you need config your php for view errors
    display_errors = On
    display_startup_errors = On
    error_reporting = 1
    log_errors = On

If you can't modify php config you have other option. Apache log register every error: 404, php, ...